# replacing div content with a click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see this question asked a lot in the related questions, but my need seems very simple compared to those examples, and sadly I'm just still too new at js to know what to remove...so at the risk of being THAT GUY, I'm going to ask my question...

I'm trying to switch out the div contents in a box depending on the button pushed.  Right now I have it working using the animatedcollapse.toggle function, but it doesn't look very good.  I want to replace it with a basic fade in on click and fade in new content on next button.

Basic idea:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="this will fade in the first_div"></li>
<li><a href="this will fade in the second_div"></li>
<li><a href="this will fade in the third_div"></li>
</ul>
<div class="first_container">
 <ul>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="second_container">
 <ul>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="third_container">
 <ul>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I've got everything working with the animated collapse, but it's just an ugly effect for this situation, so I want to change it out.

Thanks!
Joel

Comment: Joel, please share with us the jQuery you've got so far.

Comment: Right now, I'm not using jquerry for the toggle effect, I'm using this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm
but I'd like to replace it with jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joel, I think I understood what you wanted. Does [this look](http://jsbin.com/exome) right? In the code below I also used a convention where you append `js` to the class attribute on HTML so you can style your JS bits differently. If JS were disabled, all three tabs would show down in order. However, as long as JS is enabled, your code will display as desired.

You could improve this by dynamically setting the height of the `#animators` div based on the tallest height of the children, but it was getting complex enough as it was!

I changed your HTML a bit (both for testing and functionality.):

```
<div>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="animators">
    <div class="container">
     <ul>
      <li>stuff1</li>
      <li>stuff1</li>
      <li>stuff1</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <ul>
      <li>stuff2</li>
      <li>stuff2</li>
      <li>stuff2</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <ul>
      <li>stuff3</li>
      <li>stuff3</li>
      <li>stuff3</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add this to your CSS:

```
.js #animators { position: relative; height: 100px}
.js #animators div.container { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0 }
```

And use this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.documentElement.className += " js"; // Add js class to the HTML element
  $(function(){
    var $containers = $("#animators > div").hide();

    $('ul li a').each(function(i,el){
      var idx = i;
      $(this).click(function(e){
        var $target = $containers.filter(':eq(' + idx + ')');
        // Fade out visible div
        if($containers.filter(':visible').not($target).length){
          $containers.filter(':visible').fadeOut();
        }
        // Fade in new div if not already showing
        $target.not(':visible').fadeIn();
        e.preventDefault();
      })
    })
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT** Here is an alternate JavaScript block that `fadesOut` *then* `fadesIn`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.documentElement.className += " js"; // Add js class to the HTML element
  $(function(){
    var $containers = $("#animators > div").hide();

    $('ul li a').each(function(i,el){
      var idx = i;
      $(this).click(function(e){
        var $target = $containers.filter(':eq(' + idx + ')');
        // Fade out visible div
        if($containers.filter(':visible').not($target).length){
          $containers.filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $target.not(':visible').fadeIn(1000);
          });
        } else {
          $target.not(':visible').fadeIn(1000);
        }

        e.preventDefault();
      })
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: the fadeIn should really should be in a callback.

Comment: @Tony if you want it to fadeOut *then* fadeIn, you are correct. I was going for a crossfade.

Comment: @Doug good point, i wrongly assumed he wanted fade out then fade in. nice solution

Comment: Thanks for doing this work.  The sandbox model is doing exactly what I want.  For some reason, when I plug this in my code, and I push the first button, it opens the contents of ALL the divs and no other buttons do anything.
well I think I know what I did wrong, but my server just went down...:-(

Comment: Works great!  Thanks man!  now...how do I adjust the fade speed? :-D

Comment: just supply an integer to both the `.fade()` calls. So, `.fade(1000)` is 1 second, etc. You can also use `slow`, `medium`, and `fast` as well. Just pass them as strings.

Comment: Right on.  Thanks so much!  This looks great. :-D

Comment: There is a strange thing with the fade.  The first fade in is great but then fading out works, but as the fade out happens, the crossfade fade in seems to come in very quick.  Can I slow down that "crossfade-fadein"?

Comment: I added an alternate script. Try that and see if it works more like you want.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  I look forward to the day that I can look at this code and really understand it.

Comment: Great! I highly recommend the book by Cody Lindley jQuery Enlightenment. Fuel Your Coding has a review and is running a giveaway: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-enlightenment-book-review-and-giveaway/

Comment: well-I just noticed something strange...the regular nav bars on the page (not part of this script) now don't work when this javascript is there.  I can click them, but they don't go anywhere...

Comment: @Joel, I wrote my code based on what you pasted. The UL is not scoped, and as such, would apply to every UL on the page. Just change the first selector as needed `ul#links li a` and then `id="links"` to your UL surrounding your links, etc.

Comment: got it.  That's the great thing about this stuff-I just learned a lot from that mistake...Thanks, too,  for the book recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like toggle supports a [speed setting](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle#speedcallback)...maybe that would be more elegant?

Comment: The toggle effect is too busy for my needs.  I would like to replicate this: http://css-tricks.com/learning-jquery-fading-menu-replacing-content/
but I'm too new at this to know how to modify and remove all the extra bits...

Answer (score 0):

How about a [JQuery fade out - http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut) and then your callback is a fade in?

..I just saw your link in the comments, that is exactly what they are doing on CSS tricks.  Do you have a more specific question?

**UPDATE**
The visible class refers to the div that will be visible...haven't tested this but it should be about right

```
$('.first_container').click(function(){
    $('.visible').fadeOut(3000,function(){
                this.removeClass('visible');
        $('.first_container').addClass('visible');
        $('.first_container').fadeIn(3000);
    });
})
```

That is the code to reference your first_container....you can go from there

Comment: it looks great...could you give me a code example if you have time?  I've seen those pages, but I just don't know how to make that work for my code above...

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your question properly, this may be helpful for you

```
<div id="LoadMe2"><h3>Please select what to edit!</h3></div>
<script>
$('a').click(function() {
  $('#LoadMe2').load($(this).attr('href'));

  return false;
});
</script>
```

and html can be like

```
<a href="abc.php" style="text-decoration:none"><input type="button" value="edit Header menu"></a>
```

**EDIT**

sorry this helps you to fetch the content from those pages and displays it. 
keeping this post as someone else may need this